# Preprocessor symbol in library and change the symbols value while using the library

Tags: c, gcc

I have a library project with a inline function in my `Lib.h`:

```
 static inline void DoStuff(void) __attribute__ ((always_inline));
 static inline void DoStuff(void)
 {
 #if(SYMBOL == 1)
     // Stuff
 #elif(SYMBOL == 2)
     // Other stuff   
 #endif
}
```

I compile my library into `libLib.a` and set `SYMBOL=2`. Now I use this library and the header `Lib.h` in some other project. This project set `SYMBOL=1` and calls `DoStuff()` in this project. Which part of the `#if` directive gets executed? I assume that the compiler will run the part with `#if(SYMBOL == 1)` but I´m not sure. How does the compiler handle it?

Comment: `library into libLib.a and set SYMBOL=2` - how do you do that? How do you "set" "SYMBOL=2"? Show the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the correct syntax for the preprocessor directives is:

```
static inline void DoStuff(void) __attribute__ ((always_inline));
static inline void DoStuff(void)
{
#if SYMBOL == 1
    // Stuff

#elif SYMBOL == 2
    // Other stuff   

#endif
}
```

You can also leave the parentheses around the comparison if you prefer, but it isn't strictly necessary as with the regular `if` condition.

If you are not sure, which code parts are active, you can use `#warning` to make it obvious:

```
#if SYMBOL == 1
 #warning Symbol == 1
    // Stuff

#elif SYMBOL == 2
 #warning Symbol == 2
    // Other stuff  

#endif
```

Comment: Well, with `#error` compilation will fail, so `#warning` is the better option. If it isn't supported, the compiler will complain about it too, so it has almost the same effect as `#error` if it is unsupported ;)

Comment: `#warning` does work in my case, so I have verified my assumption.

Comment: The syntax with the parentheses is not wrong, they are just not needed.

Comment: @thebusybee I did not claim that, but other parts were wrong (else if, endif missing)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I rewrite this example from my mind and not copy the code new and so I missed it :). I will update my question

Comment: Right, but that hit my eye. Sorry for the noise. Anyway, you might like to expand your answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In C, lines which starts with # are **pre-processed** by the preprocessor, which means that when you compile this, the compiler will read it like this (for example, if **in the library** SYMBOL=1:

```
static inline void DoStuff(void) __attribute__ ((always_inline));
static inline void DoStuff(void)
{
    //only the stuff that were in the block of SYMBOL=1
}
```

When you compile the code into a library, it no longer knows SYMBOL.
When you change SYMBOL in your code, it will only change it for this project.
To resolve this issue, use the macros in a header:

In DoStuff.h:

```
void __do_stuff1();
void __do_stuff2();
static inline void DoStuff()
{
    #if SYMBOL==1
        __do_stuff1();
    #elif SYMBOL==2
        __do_stuff2();
    #endif
}
```

In DoStuff.c:

```
void__do_stuff1(){...}
void __do_stuff2(){...}
```